# Using Powershell to Copy Target Folders/Files from Specified Directory

Tags: powershell, scripting, devops

I am trying to dump the .yaml files inside of 4 folders (files are nested in a subfolder inside) to another directory, only copying the .yaml files into each of the 4 copied folders, excluding the subfolders. The subfolder in each directory has the same name. Ive got a script that does the first part of the copy, but it doesnt exclude the subfolders, and nests the files in their respective target folder still. Not sure what im doing wrong or what I need to fix with my script at the bottom.

The current file structure:

```
  - QA
    - Target **Connections** Folder
      - contains .yaml files
    - Several Other Folders
  - RESEARCH
    - Target **Connections** Folder
      - contains .yaml files
    - Several Other Folders
  - PROD
    - Target **Connections** Folder
    - Several Other Folders
  - DEV
    - Target **Connections** Folder
    - Several Other Folders
```

The output to the copied directory should be as follows:

````
  - QA
    - .yaml files from original "qa/Connections" subfolder
  - RESEARCH
    - .yaml files from original "research/Connections" subfolder
  - PROD
    - .yaml files from original "prod/Connections" subfolder
  - DEV
    - .yaml files from original "dev/Connections" subfolder```
````

I have the following script, but it only copies the 4 sub folders under the base directory, and all of the contents contained, I cant figure out how to drill those down to exclude everything except for the **Connections** folder, and place only the files into those 4 main environment folders.

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\TEST-REPO\hhh\data\environments"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $dest = Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.SubString($sourceDir.Length)
    if ($dest -match 'research|qa|production|global') {
        $null = New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
$sourceDir = 'C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\TEST-REPO\hhh\data\environments'
$targetDir = 'C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder'

# Create target folders
Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Directory -Name | %{
    mkdir (Join-Path $TargetDir $_) | Out-Null
}

# Copy .yaml files
Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Filter *.yaml -Recurse -Depth 2 |
   where {$_.Directory.Name -eq 'Connections'} |
      Copy-Item -Destination { '{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $TargetDir , $_.Directory.Parent.Name , $_.Name }
```

Comment: I tried that, and it seems to fail half way through with `Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\targetfolder\Connections\ggg.yaml'.`. Not sure why its failing half way on the copy item part. Also can you think of any way to filter it further to only copy from the `connections` subfolder? There are other nested folders under the environments folder that have .yaml files.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your OP, as that's probably where the error is coming from as well, since it's failing on a file that had `Connections` as its *grandparent*...

Comment: Code edited to provide additional filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-ChildItem` [`-Path` allows for wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-path). This can be combined with [-Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-filter) to only return `*.yml` files.

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\TEST-REPO\hhh\data\environments"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$sourceDir\*\Connections" -Filter '*.yml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # this assumes there are no subdirectories in the 'Connections' directory
    #  that contain any .yml files
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_.Directory.Parent.Name
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
    }
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

Update: To handle an indefinite number of subdirectories in "Connections", don't use a wildcard and instead loop through the directories in "environments" (similar to [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74295432/2410990)):

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\powershell-scripts\TEST-REPO\hhh\data\environments"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_.Name
    $connectionsDir = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'Connections'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $connectionsDir -Filter '*.yml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: This very interesting! It works, but I did notice there is one subdirectory that does have a folder inside of the connections folder. Is there a known way to account for that?

Comment: Updated answer for the case with subdirectories. It shifts the paradigm away from wildcards and adds an additional loop.